# Error: Can't find variable Stack, React Navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to develop a todolist app using react native, for which I coded the home screen. I had following some docs, but it gives me this error. Please help.
I have executed the commands in the following order.

```
 expo install react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view

 npm install @react-navigation/native

 npm install @react-navigation/stack
```

[image: t]

This is my code.

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View ,Button} from 'react-native';
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={}
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <View>
      <View style={{margin:50}}>
        <Button title="New Task"></Button>
      </View>
    </View>
    )
  }
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are not declaring Stack in your program include this line in your program:

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();
```

Add this line in your App function like this:

```
export default function App() {
  const Stack = createStackNavigator();
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to the top of your code

```
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone looking for without using class...

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

function HomeScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Home Screen</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Try on expo, [click here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hello-react-navigation)

Answer (score 0):

write this instead if you are using **react native**:

```
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
```

&&

```
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
```